# minimumFetchInterval in Firebase remote config

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm using remote config to prompt user for a new update. What should I use for the `minimumFetchInterval`?

The dilemma is that, if I keep this number too low (let's say 5 or 10 seconds), then it would increase the calls to Firebase; and, if I keep it as something like 60 minutes, then the update would be delivered late to the user.

Some advice or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Hey Jayant. Any updates here? 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Firebase documentation on [throttling in Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started):

> The default and **recommended production fetch interval for Remote Config is 12 hours**

So you should set it to 12 hours in production.

From the same page:

> **During app development**, you might want to refresh the cache very frequently (many times per hour) to let you rapidly iterate as you develop and test your app. To accommodate rapid iteration on a project with numerous developers, **you can temporarily add a property with a low minimum fetch interval** (`Settings.minimumFetchIntervalMillis`) in your app.

So you can set it *much* shorter during development, because:

> Keep in mind that this setting should be used for development only, not for an app running in production. If you're just testing your app **with a small 10-person development team, you are unlikely to hit the hourly service-side quota limits**. But **if you pushed your app out to thousands of test users with a very low minimum fetch interval, your app would probably hit this quota.**